# What NScriptType: ServerScript to use in NetSuite field value update script

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite, suitescript

I am looking to update a numeric field for multiple records with arithmetic, not just overriding the current value with a new one. To do this, I plan on uploading a file with the identifier of the item and the new value being added. Parse the file and use custom searches to find the corresponding records, then loading, updating and saving the proper record. However, how to run the script is where I get confused.

I have created previous scripts beforeLoad scripts which run on entering the edit view of an item, but I have not used any server side scripts yet (I read that when accessing files from the filing cabinet, you must use a server side script).

Any information about server script types and when to use them would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can either use a Mass/Update script, a Scheduled script or a Map/Reduce script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing a Map/Reduce script is your best bet

You can pass a fileId as a parameter and your getInputData stage can just load and return the file(which, IIRC, sends each line to your map stage). Your map stage has to ignore the header, if present, and any trailing bad lines.

I havent' been able to easily find a script that I've written that does that but I'm pretty sure I have done that.
Normally though I do something like this for processing a file into the map stage:

```js
function getInputData(){ 
    try{
        var me = runtime.getCurrentScript();
        
        var targetFileId = <number>me.getParameter({name:'custscript_kotn_att_emp_file'});
        var targetFile = file.load({id:targetFileId});

        log.audit({title: 'getting data', details:targetFile.name +' ' + targetFile.size});
        var empLines = [];
        targetFile.lines.iterator().each(line=>{
            var parts = line.value.split('|');
            if(parts.length >2 && parts.length != expectColumns.length){
                throw new Error('Unexpected line length. Had '+ parts.length +' expected '+ expectColumns.length);
            }
            if(parts.length > 2){
                empLines.push(parts);
            }
            return true;
        });

        log.audit({title: 'got employee lines', details:empLines.length});
        return empLines;
    }catch(e){
        log.error({
            title:"in input stage", 
            details : (e.message || e.toString()) + (e.getStackTrace ? (' \n \n' + e.getStackTrace().join(' \n')) : '')
        });
        return null;
    }


};

function map(ctx){
    const empLine = JSON.parse(ctx.value);
    //you have an array of the parsed line

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely look into this and see if I can't implement it. I appreciate the help!